# react-native - [object] is not usable as a native method argument

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I recently started to get this error for both iOS and Android. I don't know what is causing this problem. In all the other instances of this error, there is probably a `NaN` value or some other unexpected value but in my case, everything is a valid value. For iOS, this is happening when I am callind the `PushNotificationIOS.scheduleNotification`. For Android, it happens, when I called a native react method.

**This is only happening when I am running in dev mode**. Please let me know what could be the problem here or how can I debug this problem.

```java
2019-10-18 21:27:16.745 10843-11080/com.myapp E/ReactNativeJS: [{"fireDate":"2019-11-01T16:30:00.000Z","repeat":"2","repeatType":"weeks","creatorTimezone":"Asia/Kolkata","alarmId":"-LrU_OrkWvoCU-W8VY-A","alarmName":"Personal Reminder","type":"alarm","alarmType":"Personal","alarmDate":"2019-11-01T16:30:00.000Z","alarmAlert":"Personal Reminder - It's time.","shortAlarmAlert":"It's time.","cascadingAlarmInterval":900000,"recipientAlarmInterval":0,"alarmRingtone":{"label":"Hollywood Adventure","type":"inbuilt","value":"hollywood_adventure"},"vibrate":"true","volume":80,"version":2,"ringtoneDuration":60000,"uid":"-LrTbAdkCtVoFBfDKBwk","username":"udi","ringtonePath":"android.resource://com.myapp/raw/hollywood_adventure"}] is not usable as a native method argument
2019-10-18 21:27:16.766 10843-11080/com.myapp I/ReactNativeJS: 'Failed to print error: ', 'Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.\n\n[[34,45],[4,2],[["[{\\"fireDate\\":\\"2019-11-01T16:30:00.000Z\\",\\"repeat\\":\\"2\\",\\"repeatType\\":\\"weeks\\",\\"creatorTimezone\\":\\"Asia/Kolkata\\",\\"alarmId\\":\\"-LrU_OrkWvoCU-W8VY-A\\",\\"alarmName\\":\\"Personal Reminder\\",\\"type\\":\\"alarm\\",\\"alarmType\\":\\"Personal\\",\\"alarmDate\\":\\"2019-11-01T16:30:00.000Z\\",\\"alarmAlert\\":\\"Personal Reminder - It\'s time.\\",\\"shortAlarmAlert\\":\\"It\'s time.\\",\\"cascadingAlarmInterval\\":900000,\\"recipientAlarmInterval\\":0,\\"alarmRingtone\\":{\\"label\\":\\"Hollywood Adventure\\",\\"type\\":\\"inbuilt\\",\\"value\\":\\"hollywood_adventure\\"},\\"vibrate\\":\\"true\\",\\"volume\\":80,\\"version\\":2,\\"ringtoneDuration\\":60000,\\"uid\\":\\"-LrTbAdkCtVoFBfDKBwk\\",\\"username\\":\\"udi\\",\\"ringtonePath\\":\\"android.resource://com.myapp/raw/hollywood_adventure\\"}] is not usable as a native method argument",[{"column":20,"lineNumber":4382,"arguments":[],"methodName":"enqueueNativeCall","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":42,"lineNumber":4000,"arguments":[],"methodName":"fn","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":41,"lineNumber":284071,"arguments":[],"methodName":"scheduleNotification","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":53,"lineNumber":213975,"arguments":[],"methodName":"cancelOrRescheduleNotificationForAlarm","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":53,"lineNumber":213917,"arguments":[],"methodName":"markAlarmAsAcknowledged","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":17,"lineNumber":197088,"arguments":[],"methodName":"withConnectAndAuthenticationOptional","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":67,"lineNumber":213997,"arguments":[],"methodName":"onIAmUp","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":47,"lineNumber":53662,"arguments":[],"methodName":"touchableHandlePress","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":null,"lineNumber":null,"arguments":[],"methodName":"touchableHandlePress","file":"[native code]"},{"column":36,"lineNumber":53205,"arguments":[],"methodName":"_performSideEffectsForTransition","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":null,"lineNumber":null,"arguments":[],"methodName":"_performSideEffectsForTransition","file":"[native code]"},{"column":46,"lineNumber":53131,"arguments":[],"methodName":"_receiveSignal","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":null,"lineNumber":null,"arguments":[],"methodName":"_receiveSignal","file":"[native code]"},{"column":26,"lineNumber":53010,"arguments":[],"methodName":"touchableHandleResponderRelease","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":null,"lineNumber":null,"arguments":[],"methodName":"touchableHandleResponderRelease","file":"[native code]"},{"column":21,"lineNumber":14049,"arguments":[],"methodName":"invokeGuardedCallbackImpl","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":42,"lineNumber":14145,"arguments":[],"methodName":"invokeGuardedCallback","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":36,"lineNumber":14149,"arguments":[],"methodName":"invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"},{"column":48,"lineNumber":14256,"arguments":[],"methodName":"executeDispatch","file":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/in
2019-10-18 21:27:16.770 10843-11080/com.myapp E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling RCTEventEmitter.receiveTouches
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: [{"fireDate":"2019-11-01T16:30:00.000Z","repeat":"2","repeatType":"weeks","creatorTimezone":"Asia/Kolkata","alarmId":"-LrU_OrkWvoCU-W8VY-A","alarmName":"Personal Reminder","type":"alarm","alarmType":"Personal","alarmDate":"2019-11-01T16:30:00.000Z","alarmAlert":"Personal Reminder - It's time.","shortAlarmAlert":"It's time.","cascadingAlarmInterval":900000,"recipientAlarmInterval":0,"alarmRingtone":{"label":"Hollywood Adventure","type":"inbuilt","value":"hollywood_adventure"},"vibrate":"true","volume":80,"version":2,"ringtoneDuration":60000,"uid":"-LrTbAdkCtVoFBfDKBwk","username":"udi","ringtonePath":"android.resource://com.myapp/raw/hollywood_adventure"}] is not usable as a native method argument
```